# Checking whether elements found in a set is found in another set

Tags: python, function, set

I have three sets containing unique elements. I want to add a condition such that if an element is not present in `set_out` and `frozen`, then it have to be present in `set_general` for the downstream process to happen. I am only showing the relevant part of the actual code. I am stuck with writing this condition. Suggestions will be heavily appreciated.

Eg: `set_out = set([2,4,8,3,5])`, `frozen = set([2,5,12,15])`, `set_general = set([2,4,8,3,5,12,15,20,25])`. What i want is if an element is not found in `set_out` and `frozen`, then that specific element have to be present in `set_general` for boolean `initially` to be True.

```
def flipper(set_out,frozen,set_general):
    initially = False
    for_symmetric_diff = set_out.symmetric_difference_update(frozen)
    for i in for_symmetric_diff:
        if for_symmetric_diff not in set_general:
            initially = False
            return False
        else:
            initially = True
            return True
```

Comment: Why don't you try using set operations like union and intersection? I am not able to understand your question very well.

Comment: in the for loop you `return` a boolean after the first iteration, it makes your question confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to foreach sets, python lets you check if a set contains an element by using the keyword "in", adapt it to your needs (in this example if the elt is in one of the sets it return true, false otherwise) :

```
def flipper(set_out, frozen, set_general, elt):
    return elt in set_out or elt in frozen or elt in set_general

set_out = set([2,4,8,3,5])
frozen = set([2,5,12,15])
set_general = set([2,4,8,3,5,12,15,20,25])

print(flipper(set_out, frozen, set_general, 50))
print(flipper(set_out, frozen, set_general, 25))
```